# Set user account to expire after a given time

Tags: php, mysql, sql

The users table in a database has the following fields(among others):

- date created (the date when the user has joined)
- confirmed  (set to 1 if the user has confirmed his email)
- approved  (set to 1 if the user has beed approved by the admin)

What I would like to do is to create another row, called "period" which will be updated to 
1 if the user wants to join for 1 month, 
2 if he wants to join for 6 months, and 
3 if he wants to join for 1 year

I wonder if it is possible to somehow automatically set the approved from 1 to 0 after the chosen period has expired.
I am just asking for some ideas... I hope that after reading your opinions I might come with the best solution in my particular case....

how would you aproach such an issue?

Comment: Set an expiration date, don't let the user log in in the date has expired. simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is with a view.  You can compare the current time to the end time for the subscription:

```
create view v_users as
    select u.*,
           (now() < (datecreated + interval (case when period = 1 then 1
                                                  when period = 2 then 6
                                                  when period = 3 then 12
                                              end) month
                    )
           ) as approved
    from users u;
```

Comment: I do like this approach as you end up with historical subscription information, and can revoke subscriptions easily.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest following approach -

1. Instead of adding a new row, you should add another column e.g. **subscription_type** with type **enum**, **values** - 0 - Valid for 0 days, 1 - Valid for 1 month, 2 - Valid for 6 months, 3 - Valid for 1 year.
2. You can have a cron job which can check the expiration and handle the stuff.